# Launch file after PHP service restart/reload

Tags: php

Is it possible to execute a file after a regular PHP service restart ?

```
service php5 restart
```

I know that i can accomplish this like with `service php restart; php -f /path/to/file.php` but i don't know if this could be automatically run each time the service is restarted/reloaded even by the system itself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the init (Debian: /etc/init.d) script and add the additional command(s) there. If you need it on multiple servers I would recommend compiling your own package version.